# How can I get elapsed time for each clause in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Profile to get execution plan. However, it returns only the total elapsed time but not the elapsed time for each step.
My question is, how to get the elapsed time for each step beacause my query turns 3hours and I need to see where does it take a lot of time.

Thank you.

Comment: While it would take a bit of elbow grease, you can probably gather the statistics you want with user defined procedures (https://neo4j.com/developer/procedures-functions/). I don't know how useful this is, but you might be able to implement a crud stopwatch with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, one uses the number of "db hits" for each operation (as reported by `PROFILE` or `EXPLAIN`) as a relative measure for how expensive that operation is. Your goal should be to minimize the number of DB hits.

Comment: I know this but sometimes procedure call uses x dbhits and took a lot of time than a clause takes the same dbhits so it is not a good measure

Comment: True, db hits are not a perfect substitute for execution time, but it is basically the only measure you have. If you see a large number of DB hits for an operation, then that is a hint that you should take a closer look at the reason. Performance tuning is not a science, and requires some work on your part to tease out what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for this